# Finding out if a set is a projective or an affine set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Given the following subsets of $\mathbb{C}^5$ $$X=\cases{z_1^2+z_2^3+z_3^4+z_4^5+z_5^6=1\\z_1z_2z_3z_4z_5=1}\\Y=\{z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_4+z_4z_5=0\}\\Z=X-(X\cap Y)$$Determine whether $Z$ is a projective or an affine set.

Since $Y$ is a hyperplane of one homogenous polynomial that is an affine set $\subseteq \mathbb{A}^5$. An isomorphism can be also defined between $Y\to Y^\prime\subseteq \mathbb{A}^5$. About $X$ both equations are not homogenous and I can't find a precise isomorphism between it to another set (either affine, or projective). How can I find if $X$ is projective?

If it's projective: $X\cap Y$ will be a hyper surface with the limitations from $X$ and $Y$. Does that mean that $Z$ is affine?

Comment: $Y$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^5$, it is not projective. If you take the same equation in $\mathbb{P}^5$ is would be projective. But your hypothesis is that $Y$ lives in $\mathbb{A}^5$.

Comment: That's because $\mathbb{C}^5\subseteq\mathbb{A}^5$? What about $X$?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^5 = \mathbb{A}^5$, but in algebraic geometry $\mathbb{C}^5$ is nonstandard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general theorem which suits here as well.

> If $X$ is an affine variety and $Y$ is a hypersurface (=affine variety
>   that is given by 1 equation), Then $X-(X\cap Y)$ is affine.

Thus your set $Z$ is affine. Since a set which is both affine and projective is precisely finite, $Z$ is not projective.

Comment: but why this theorem is correct?

Comment: This should be proved in a basic course on algebraic geometry; I'm sure it may be found in a relevant book.

Comment: Can you not provide a standard reference (even if it differs from the hone Danis uses)? "It's in some book" is not helpful to those who are not familiar with algebraic geometry.

Comment: It is not that hard to google "Algebraic geometry books", and a quick look at the content will give you the answer.

Comment: anyways, here: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/725/class9.pdf you can find a sketch of the proof.

Comment: See also here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538136/complements-of-hypersurfaces-in-a-projective-space-is-affine

Answer (score 0):

The projection  on the first $5$ coordinates maps 
$$\tilde X=\cases{z_1^2+z_2^3+z_3^4+z_4^5+z_5^6=1\\
z_1z_2z_3z_4z_5=1\\
(z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_4+z_4z_5) \cdot z_6 =1
}$$

isomorphically onto $X \backslash Y$. A concrete form of the concise statement by @Mike: